# Cannot read property 'push' of null

Tags: javascript, github, localstorage, vue.js

Для обучения делал для себя органайзер на vue.js. Локально все работает и никаких ошибок нет. Как только я заливаю это все на githubPages выбивает ошибку:

> "Cannot read property 'push' of null".

В чем дело? https://jozephpalka.github.io/vue.js-Buyers-list/ --> ссылка на githubPages

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        itemList: getLocalData(),
        productName: "",
        productAmount: ''
    },
    methods: {
        addItem: function(e) {
            if (!this.productName || !this.productAmount) {
                alert('Пустое значение');
            } else {
                app.itemList.push({
                    name: this.productName,
                    count: this.productAmount
                });
                var localStoragekey =1;
                localStorage.setItem(localStoragekey++,JSON.stringify(this.itemList));
                // Saving data of items in localStorage
            }
            // Clearing inputs after adding item
            this.productName='';
            this.productAmount='';
        },
        purchased: function(index) {
            this.itemList.splice(index, 1);
            localStorage.setItem(1,JSON.stringify(this.itemList));
        }
    }
});
// Loading JSON data from localStorage
function getLocalData(){
    var reseved = localStorage.getItem(1);
    reseved = JSON.parse(reseved);
    return reseved;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что Ваш массив может быть пустым и не инициализированным `null`, поэтому метод `push` не срабатывает. Можно добавить проверку и создать его в случае необходимости:

```
app.itemList = app.itemList || [];
app.itemList.push({
   name: this.productName,
   count: this.productAmount
});
```

Comment: Господи, как я сам не додумался. Спасибо большое.

Comment: Еще 26 секунд :)